# jQuery Return value undefined

Tags: jquery

FIXED! THANKS! See "Corrected Code" below.

The goal is to get data back from the dialog box. I have seen lots of articles, but could not get any of them to work, so I decided to use a web service to pass the data back and forth between the dialog box and the underlying page.

All of the code is in place except the code that reads values coming back from the web service. I can see in the debugger that the data is being passed back, but when I return to the caller, the returned data is undefined.

jQuery function getLocal calls AJAX, gets good data back, but when it returns to the function that calls it (verbListShow), the returned value is "undefined".

This is all happening in an ASP.NET page that is written largely in jQuery, and opens a jQuery dialog box.

```
function getLocal(name) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/GetLocalVariable",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        success: function (data) {
            var rtn = data.d;
            return rtn;
        }
    });
}
```

The above code works, but when called, rtn is undefined. Here is the caller:

```
function verbListShow(dutyNumber) {

    $('#dlgDutyList').dialog({
        modal: true,
        show: "slide",
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            setLocal("DUTYNUMBER", dutyNumber);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Select": function () {
                var id = getLocal("VERBID"); // <*** Returns undefined
                var verb = getLocal("VERB"); // <*** Returns undefined
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/SetDuty",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ dutyNum: dutyNumber, id: id, verb: verb }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        if (data.ErrorFound) {
                            showMessage(data.ErrorMessage, 2, true);
                        }
                        else {
                            log('Set Duty: ' + data.StringReturn + ' (' + data.intReturn + ')');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("updateDuty: "
                            + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });

                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }

    });
    $('#dlgDutyList').dialog('open');
```

FIXED CODE:

```
function getLocal(name) {
var rtn = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/GetLocalVariable",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        success: function (data) {
            rtn = data.d;
        }
    });
return rtn;
}
```

Comment: What does the web service return on posting name to it? Does it have d field in it? show some sample data..

Comment: `return rtn;` You can't return from the ajax success callback. I suggest either not using the getLocal function or having it return the jqXHR object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It defeats the purpose of AJAX to use it synchronously (*AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript And Xml*).

Now you cannot `return` a value from the success method, but you can store it in a variable and then return that

```
function getLocal(name) {
    var returnValue;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/GetLocalVariable",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        success: function (data) {
            returnValue = data.d;
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

---

But the *proper* way would be to use a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
function getLocal(name, resultset) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/GetLocalVariable",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        success: function (data) {
            resultset[name] = data.d;
        }
    });
}
```

and call it

```
"Select": function() {
    var results = {};
    var self = this;
    $.when(getLocal("VERBID", results), getLocal("VERB", results)).then(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/SetDuty",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                dutyNum: dutyNumber,
                id: results.VERBID,
                verb: results.VERB
            }),
            success: function(data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                if (data.ErrorFound) {
                    showMessage(data.ErrorMessage, 2, true);
                }
                else {
                    log('Set Duty: ' + data.StringReturn + ' (' + data.intReturn + ')');
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("updateDuty: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    }).always(function(){
        $(self).dialog("close");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything is because $.ajax function don't return any value because of it's asynchronous behaviour, my advice is to make second parameter for `getLocal` method called "callback".

Proper way is to do it like so:

```
function getLocal(name, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/GetLocalVariable",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        success: function (data) {
            var rtn = data.d;
            callback(rtn);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, your main code have to look like that (asynchronous code):

```
//some code here
buttons: {
            "Select": function () {
                getLocal("VERBID", function(id) {
                     getLocal("VERB", function(verb) { 
                        $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           async: false,
                           url: "WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/SetDuty",
                           dataType: 'json',
                        //some code here
                     });
                });
//some code here
```

To improve this code, to make two asynchronous calls at once, you can use [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, and run `.resolve(data)` on it just after all ajax calls obtained proper response.

Comment: Thanks to both responders. I got the code working quickly because of your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by set ****`async: false`**** .

I create new global function called `sendRequest(type, url, data)` with three parameters to be called every time everywhere

```
function sendRequest(type, url, data) {
    let returnValue = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        async: false,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) {
            returnValue = resp;
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now call function

```
        let data = {
            email: 'tet@gmail.com',
            password: 'warning',
        };
        let  response =  sendRequest('POST', 'http://localhost/signin')}}", data);
        console.log(response );
```

> Important **Note** in code is :  `async: false`